# Проблемы с регулярным выражением в Java

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Здравствуйте. Мне необходимо парсить html, я не стал пользоваться готовыми парсерами, а решил написать регулярное выражение. Само регулярное выражение работает нормально, проверял на [данном](http://www.regexpr.ru/) ресурсе, но вот в Java, что то не хочет работать. [Код](https://github.com/jetuuuu/googleBookmarks4XML/tree/master/src) выложил на гитхаб.

P.S. Пример html файла (выдергиваю название сайта, вместе с http://):

`<DT><A HREF="http://site.ru/" ………>text</A>`

Comment: стопе, парсить html регулярными выражениями?? да ты оригинал) скачай jericho и не парься

Comment: ну не хочу я, чтобы была какая то зависимость от внешних библиотек, тем более мне совсем простые вещи выдернуть из html, название сайта и текст

Comment: что, никто больше ничем не может помочь ?

Comment: Не понятное выражение и непонятно как оно могло работать:  

    <http:\S*\\/>
Читается оно так: **<http** после которого не пробел ноль или более раз, за которым обратный слэш, прямой слэш и **>**   
Укажите конкретно какой исходный текст и какой ожидаемый результат.  
Кода у Вас не очень много, поэтому привлекать гит излишне- размещайте малые блоки кода  самом вопросе.

Comment: ну смотрите вот из такого html 

<DT><A HREF="http://habrahabr.ru/" ADD_DATE="1360236862" ICON="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAUUlEQVQ4jWNgGGjAyMDAwFC/YMN/cjQ3JgQwMlHqAhZ0gYZ4fwR74UacYjBAsQuo7wVkgOx0mrmAtgY0LNyIEer0dQFdDMBMiVj8jC8cKHYBAKwREpjP4+f+AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">Лучшие за сутки / Посты / Хабрахабр</A>

я хочу получить просто http://habrahabr.ru/

Comment: с флагом игнора регистра выражение делаете?

Comment: поставте свой комментарий как ответ, отмечу, спасибо вам

Comment: не за что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.

```
"<a.*?\\shref\\s*=\\s*\"[^\"]*\""
```

> Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternURL,  **Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE**)